# relative background color on hover

Tags: html, css, background-color

I have a simple html code that is below:

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: x-large;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#home-btn {
  background: orange;
}

#panel-btn {
  background: yellowgreen;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<button title="home" id="home-btn" class="fa fa-home"></button>
<button title="panel" id="panel-btn" class="fa fa-key"></button>
```

how can i set background color to a darker color than default background color?

here is a gif from a page that has what i want:
[image: the hover effect]

sorry for bad english.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: @JoachimHaglund I know hover selector, but i don't know how to set hover background from default background.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. Remember that you can (and should) accept one answer that solves the problem you described, if there is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [CSS filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter):

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: x-large;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: filter .2s;
}

button:hover {
  filter: brightness(0.9);
}

#home-btn {
  background: orange;
}

#panel-btn {
  background: yellowgreen;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<button title="home" id="home-btn" class="fa fa-home"></button>
<button title="panel" id="panel-btn" class="fa fa-key"></button>
```

From what I see in that GIF, it's probably rather increase of saturation that you want:

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: x-large;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: filter .2s;
}

button:hover {
  filter: saturate(400%);
}

#home-btn {
  background: orange;
}

#panel-btn {
  background: yellowgreen;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<button title="home" id="home-btn" class="fa fa-home"></button>
<button title="panel" id="panel-btn" class="fa fa-key"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: x-large;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover{
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  filter: saturate(400%);
}

#home-btn {
  background: orange;
}

#panel-btn {
  background: yellowgreen;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<button title="home" id="home-btn" class="fa fa-home"></button>
<button title="panel" id="panel-btn" class="fa fa-key"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: x-large;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: brightness(0.8);
}

#home-btn {
  background: orange;
}
#home-btn:hover {
  width: 170px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  filter: none;
 }

#panel-btn {
  background: yellowgreen;
  right: 0;
}
#panel-btn:hover {
  width: 170px;
  height: 60px;
   border-radius: 30px;
    filter: none;
 }
```

```html
<button title="home" id="home-btn" class="fa fa-home"></button>
<button title="panel" id="panel-btn" class="fa fa-key"></button>
```